# How can i disable SSL functionality in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web

While creating a Web API project in Visual Studio using C#, I forgot to uncheck the configure HTTPS property, now I am not able to hit the https url, due to SSL error.

How can I disable the SSL functionality in Visual Studio now?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Go to the app properties and uncheck "Enable SSL"